# Changing length of multiple images in Premiere Elements 7

Tags: adobe-premiere

I recorded a bunch of still images for a time lapse and now I would like to make a movie out of them.  I import them easily enough and I can drag them all at once into the timeline and it works fine.  The problem is the length each image is displayed is 5 seconds which is way to long.

How can I make this shorter for all the images at once?  I can't seem to select all or drag or find a way to change the default length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured out my own question.

If you select all of your images and drag them to the sceneline you can pick 'Add as Grouped Slideshow' and select how many frames you want to use.

If anyone knows how to stretch multiple frames already added to a project, that still would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Select multiple still images that are already in the sceneline, go to clip/ speed / duration >> Mark the check box to add ripple effect >> edit the new time duration . Then the new duration is added to the images that are already in the sceneline and it wouldn't leave empty spaces between still images.

Comment: This was the trick I was missing! Perfection! Changing duration is easy unless you don't know about the check box that lets it actually WORK.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default of 5 seconds to whatever you want in one of the preferences screens.  It uses fps not seconds, but the math is easy.
You would have to remove all your items and then add them back to your project. 
Doesn't help for items already in your sceneline.